# Changing recyclerView child layout at runtime.

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make some modifications to the layout of a recyclerView child at runtime. This means for example switching between two images  in a child view as the user touches on it. How can i do it ? Do i have to rebind the ViewHolder? Thank you in advance

Comment: There is some mechanism like "dirty", I cant recall it atm but the idea is You mark the child dirty and notify adapter so it will reinflate your child and you can make modifications then (basing on position argument)

Answer (score 1):

You have a Viewholder class that has a reference to the view passed into it when you create it. So extend the Viewholder class and create a setContent method in that class. There you can set an OnClick listener or whatever is needed for your view.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
   //cast the viewholder here to the correct viewholder type
   MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
   myViewHolder.setContent();
}
```

---

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

View mView;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;
}

@Override
public void setContent() {
    //set click listeners here
}
```